# How to sync ProgressBar in a loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, winforms, progress-bar

I try to sync progress bar in a loop with filling label consecutive digits. But my label finishes earlier than progress bar. The picture below shows that situation.

[image]

I use second thread to do this long process. Here is my test code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim watek As System.Threading.Thread

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        watek = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf DoSomething)
        watek.Start()
    End Sub


    Private Sub DoSomething()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim max As Integer = 10000
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = max
        ProgressBar1.Step = 1

        Do Until i > ProgressBar1.Maximum
            ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
            Label1.Text = i
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here is my question - why is it happening? Why progress bar is not sync with label? Please can anyone explain me this? How to get expected result?

Comment: Ugh, never do this: `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False`.  Just read-up on using a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Or read up on delegates - that is how you access controls from a diff thread.

Answer (score 3):

one thing you can do here is check if the **maximum value of progress bar is coming in the label or not** and if it is coming and still the value is not being displayed as it should then just write "**this.Refresh();**" this will force show the changes on UI.

Answer (score 1):

A progressbar always needs some "refresh" time.

You can set the value of a Progressbar to a thousand, it needs about 2 seconds to fill up al the way to that value.

Try this:

```
For i = 0 to max
    ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
    If (i mod 100) = 0 Then
        Application.Doevents()
    End If
Next
```

Note: i don't condone your way if coding (Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False) but thats not the 
issue right now